# NoMethodError in Orders#show , undefined method `grand_total' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm want to show the grand_total to the show page and i have do a partial file to put in the table, in inside i want to grab the orderproduct data and show to front , but it show me this error. It seem like i didn't define method grand_total, but not sure how to solve it.

Orders controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

 def supplier
  @supplier = Supplier.find(params[:id])
 end

 def outlet
  @outlet = Outlet.find(params[:id])
 end

 def index
  @orders = Order.all
 end

 def show
  @orders = Order.all
  @order_products = OrderProduct.all
 end

def new
 @order = Order.new
 @supplier = Supplier.all
 @outlet = Outlet.all
 @products = Product.all
end

def create
 @order = Order.new(order_params)
 @supplier_id = Supplier.all
 @outlet_id = Outlet.all
 if @order.save
  product_ids = params[:product_ids]
  product_ids.each do |product_id|
    OrderProduct.create(order_id: @order.id, product_id: product_id)
  end
   flash[:success] = "Succesful create!"
   redirect_to @order
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end

private

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:supplier_id,:quantity, :grand_total, :order_date,
                                :delivery_date, :delivery_address, :outlet_id)
 end
end
```

_orderproduct.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
 <ul class="responsive-table">
  <li class="table-header">
   <div class="col col-1">Product</div>
   <div class="col col-2">Price</div>
   <div class="col col-4">Grand_total</div>
  </li>
  <% @order_products.each do |order_product| %>
  <li class="table-row">
   <div class="col col-1" data-label="Product"><%= order_product.product.name %></div>
   <div class="col col-2" data-label="Price"><%= order_product.product.price %></div>
   <div class="col col-4" data-label="Grand_total"><%= order_product.order.grand_total %></div>
  <% end %>
 </ul>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title)%>

<h2 class="dashboard">Order details</h2>

<div class="row">
 <aside class="col-md-4">
  <section class="stats">
   <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
  </section>
  <%= render 'orders/orderproduct' %>
  <div class="side">
   <button class="button-30"><%= link_to "Back to home", home_path %></button>
  </div>
 </aside>
</div>
```

[Error show in website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6mID.png)

Comment: can you check that is all the order_products has an order or have you defined relationship between then in model ?

Comment: Please add model code snippet

Comment: Add a model code snipped please.

Answer (score 1):

The only place in your examples on which you call `grant_total` is this:

```
<%= order_product.order.grand_total %>
```

The error message tells that there is a *NoMethodError in Orders#show, undefined method `grand_total` for `nil:NilClass`*. This means you are calling `grant_total` on something that is `nil` and not the type of object you expect. This can only happen when `order_product.order` returned `nil`. And that means you have an `order_product` in your database that doesn't have an `order` assigned.

There are several ways to fix that, depending on what you want to achieve:

- add a validation that ensures that all order_products have an order assigned.
- backfill missing orders in the database
- exclude order products without associated order when loading or
- checking if there is an order and only then outputting its grant total

Answer (score 0):

you can use debugger to see which variable is returning nil value.
Check and work from there.